# Replicate Xcode Cmd + R from a command line

Tags: xcode, vim, makefile

What I am trying to achieve is editing code in `vim` then running `make` and that would invoke the same functionality as <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in Xcode: build and launch a simulator with latest changes.

What actual commands are invoked and what parameters are used in this process? Is there a way to view this from Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `xcodebuild` from project's directory. Running with `--help` parameter will reveal all the stuff that you need - which project to build, which target to run, which sdk to use (iphoneos or iphonesimulator). Usually the call looks like this:

```
xcodebuild -project MyProject -target MyApplication -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator5.1
```

Comment: do you know how to launch a simulator with a latest build? Aciu.

Comment: The simulator part is defined by the `-sdk` parameter. Have you tried running given command line by replacing the parameters with your project values?

Comment: yes, I did run xcodebuild -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator5.1 to build, but the simulator is not launched.